# Connecting pyspark cluster installed in an server from another server

Tags: pyspark

My **PySpark** cluster is installed in one server say `10.45.25.30` and I wants to run my PySpark code in another server lets take `10.45.32.67` by connecting to the PySpark cluster installed in `10.45.25.30`.
How can I to connect to the PySpark cluster that is being installed in another server from my current server?

Comment: Do you want to combine different Spark instances in one single cluster?

Comment: What I want like, I have a server 'A' where my pyspark code is there but with no pyspark package being installed. But I have a another server 'B' with pyspark installed in it. So is there any possible way I can run my pyspark code in server 'A' by connecting to the pyspark cluster of server 'B'